# cqlsh command not working in cassandra 2.0.8

Tags: python, windows, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I downloaded cassandra 2.0.8 and installed python 2.7.6 and set path of python.(also tried with 2.7.3 but)

now after starting cassandra server executing

cqlsh or python cqlsh localhost 9160

it is giving me error of

```
Unsupported CQL version: Provided version 3.1.1 is not supported by this server
```

(supported: 2.0.0, 3.0.1)

so am i doing something wrong over here?

i am using jdk7

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
cqlsh --cqlversion=3.0.1 localhost 9160
```

Answer (score 1):

That symptom looks like the case where an older 1.x Cassandra server is actually starting, rather than the 2.0.8 you downloaded. See [[CASSANDRA-6049] Cassandra 2.0.0 distribution - CQL supported versions issue - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6049) for an example.